# Azure Dynamic membership rules

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9kWN.png)

The question is: Which users are members of ADGroup1 and ADGroup2? To answer, select the appropriate options in the answer area.

So the clue to solve this question are: '"user.city -contains "SEA" and
user.city -contains "Sea*"' statements.

I undestand that the -match is like a regex and the * is going to match everything like Seaaaaa or Sea and in azure this type of things are not case sensitive.

But how -contains works? is like this ExampleSeaExample or SeaExample and the string Sea is contained?

Comment: The Contains operator does partial string matches but not item in a collection matches. Refer this MS Document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership#supported-expression-operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how -contains works? is like this ExampleSeaExample or SeaExample and the string Sea is contained ? could you help me out please?

In the above example contains will find the string Sea without being case sensitive and will filter ExampleSeaExample, SeaExample and also SEAexample and add it in the dynamic security group.

*Refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership#supported-expression-operators) to understand Contains and other expression concepts.*

Contains as the name suggests will check if a particular word contains a particular string without being case sensitive.

**Dynamic Security filter example:-**

[image]

***The above filter will add the User with Property City that contains a string Lo > Here the User with City name London and london both will be added.***

Now, coming to your question:-

> Which users are members of ADGroup1 and ADGroup2?

***ADGroup1 is a security group with filter - '"user.city -contains "SEA" So User1- Seattle, User2- Sea, User3- SEATTLE, User4- SEA will be added in the ADGroup1 as all of them contains Sea inside.***